# HttpHandler reponse complete event when called from Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, .net, silverlight, mvvm, httphandler

I have a Silverlight 5 MVVM app sitting behind ASP.NET.  There is a button in SL wired to an ICommand in the VM that calls for the export of a specific file when clicked like so:

```
public class ReportViewModel : IViewModel

    ............

    private void RunReport()
    {
            var uriPath = string.Format(@"Handlers/ReportHandler.ashx");
            var reportDateString = ReportDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            var documentName = String.Format("FinalReport.{0}", reportDateString);
            var uri = new Uri(uriPath, UriKind.Relative);

            var linkToDownload =
                string.Format(
                    "/{0}?reportName={1}&date={2}",
                    uri,
                    documentName,
                    reportDateString
                );

            var finalUri = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.ToString() + linkToDownload;
            HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(finalUri));
    }

    ............

}
```

This works well since it fires the call for the report which can take a while and the user can keep working within the UI.  The Handler looks something like this:

```
public class ReportHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var reportName = context.Request.QueryString["reportName"];
        var dateString = context.Request.QueryString["date"];
        var limitString = context.Request.QueryString["dataLimit"];

        DateTime date;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out date))
            return;

        var functions = new ExcelReportFunctions();
        var bytes = functions.GetSummaryReport(date);

        if (bytes != null && bytes.Length > 0)
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.Expires = -1;
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.Response.Charset = "";
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + reportName.Replace(" ", "%20") + ".xlsx");
            context.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            context.Response.Flush();
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

But what I would like to do is disable the button while the report is being generated but I am not sure how best hook it in.  I could use an HttpWebRequest in Silverlight but then that would require processing the file (which is fairly big) and exporting to the user through silverlight rather then the direct response which seems inefficient.

Thanks for any help.